# Parashas Korach: and take every man his censer, and put incense in them: why this procedure?

Tags: commentaries, moshe-rabbeinu, parshat-korach, korach

In parashas Korach, we read about the complaint of Korach that Moshe Rabbeinu and Aharon HaKohen took to much upon themselves.

The Torah writes (Bamidbar 16:3):

> and they gathered themselves together against Moshe and against Aharon, and said to them, You take too much upon you, seeing all the congregation are holy, every one of them, and the L-rd is among them: why then do you raise yourselves up above the congregation of the L-rd?

On the words, "why then do you raise yourselves up above the congregation of the L-rd?", the Maharal of Prague [(Gur Aryeh, ad loc.)](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.16.3?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Gur_Aryeh_on_Bamidbar.16.3.2&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) explains that Korach and the others had no difficulty in Moshe Rabbeinu being the "king" of B'nei Yisrael. They did not reject his leadership over the Jewish People. They did, however, reject the fact that both Moshe and Aharon were being involved in the priestlyhood.

> Regarding the priesthood, however, they said it was not necessary at all.

Let's backtrack to the point where we read that Aharon was appointed as a Kohen Gadol. The [Ibn Ezra (Shemos 28:1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.28.1?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en) writes that Aharonwas chosen to be sanctified to the L-rd so that the priests would make atonement for Israel. Aharon was chosen because of the importance of Nahshon’s family.

The annotation to that posuk, provided by H. Norman Strickman and Arthur M. Silver, explains:

> Aharon was chosen because he married a woman belonging to the respected family of Nahshon. Aharon's wife was Elisheba, the daughter of Amminadab, the sister of Nahshon (Ex. 6:23), prince of the tribe of Judah.

Rabbi Jonathan Sacks zt"l [(Hierarchy and Politics: The Never-Ending Story, Korach 5776, 5783)](https://www.rabbisacks.org/covenant-conversation/korach/hierarchy-politics-never-ending-story/) says [(quoted in Torah Tidbits 1520, p. 18-22)](https://assets.torahtidbits.com/2023/06/13232657/1520-Korach.pdf):

> [...] Second, assemble allies. Korach himself was a Levite. His grievance was that Moses had appointed his brother Aaron as High Priest. Evidently he felt that as Moses’ cousin – he was the son of Yitzhar, brother of Moses’ and Aaron’s father Amram – the position should have gone to him. He thought it unfair that both leadership roles should have gone to a single family within the clan.

The Torah records that Moshe responed to the complaint that was brought before him by Korach.

Moshe said:

> Tomorrow morning the L-rd will show who is his, and who is holy; and will cause him to come near to him: even him whom he has chosen will he cause to come near to him [(Bamidbar 16:5)](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.16.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

The Sforno [(ad loc.)](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.16.5?lang=bi&with=Sforno&lang2=en) says that *"ואת הקדוש והקריב אליו, He, G’d, Himself will make it plain who is entitled and worthy to offer sacrifices in His honour".* - Moshe Rabbeinu might have felt that if He would say "I was chosen by G-d", this would provoke the situation and Korach's respond. This might be why Moshe "played it safe" and said that G-d Himself would tell who was chosen by Him.

A [few posukim later](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.16.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), we read that Moshe instructed Korach ([and the assembly of Korach](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.16.21?lang=bi&with=Rabbeinu%20Chananel&lang2=en)) that they [(each of the 250 men)](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.16.17?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) needed to take a vessel/pot and put incense in it. They would need to bring it to the tent of meeting and present it before G-d. What happens? G-d consumes them [(see Chizkuni, ad loc.)](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.16.21?lang=bi&with=Chizkuni&lang2=en).

The question is as follows: Why would G-d chose for this specific procedure, e.g. they would try to offer something before G-d, but would be consumed. Why did G-d not say to the people that He chose Moshe and Aharon because of their virtues etc..? Are there meforshim that discuss this? Why especially this kind of way to demonstrate who G-d chose?